# Use Timer In Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, timer

I am Creating a web app

on my button click there is an `insert query` if after (`15 seconds`) it is unable to insert, it should show the message (`in alert`) the internet connection is very slow Please Wait For A While

How To Use timer in angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

Instead if $timeout, IMO $interval will be of more help.
Below is the sample snippet for doing the same

```
function FetchCtrl($scope, $http, $interval) {
  $scope.method = 'GET';
  $scope.url = 'http-hello.html';

  $scope.count = 0;
  var stop;

  var stopInterval = function(){            
      $interval.cancel(stop); 
      stop = undefined;
      $scope.count=0;
  }  
  $scope.fetch = function() {
    stop = $interval(function(){
                        $scope.count++;
                        if($scope.count === 15){

                          //showAlert here

                          stopInterval();
                        }
                    },1000);
    $http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url})
      .success(function(data, status) {
        stopInterval();
        $scope.status = status;
        $scope.data = data;
      })
      .error(function(data, status) {
        stopInterval();        
        $scope.status = status;
        $scope.data = "Request failed";
    });
  };

  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    // Make sure that the interval is destroyed too
    stopInterval();
  });



}
```

Here the interval is started as soon as http request is made, it updates the counter every second for 15 seconds. Then once 15 is reached, alert is shown and the  interval is stopped.
If the request is completed, then also the interval is stopped.

PS: While using $interval, one thing should be kept in mind : Cancel the interval when scope is destroyed otherwise it will continue to execute callback even when we have moved out of that controller scope.

Comment: what is advantage of $interval with count over $timeout?

Comment: The answer was posted in pure angularjs, without jquery ajax call. The advantage here being that the interval will be cancelled if request is returned before 15 seconds. The snippet clearly shows all the scenarios